# Pourquoi « s’avérer exact » est-il incorrect ?

Tags: usage

J'ai entendu dire que la phrase suivante est incorrecte :

> L'histoire du jeune homme s'est avérée exacte.

Savez-vous pourquoi car elle me parait tout à fait correcte.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remarque 1 dans le TLF.

> Étant donné que le verbe *avérer* comprend le radical « vrai » (latin *verus*), la plupart des grammairiens déclarent incorrect l'emploi d'expressions comme *s'avérer vrai*, *faux*, *exact*, *inexact*. Hanse 1949 observe : « *Je n'hésiterais pas à dire : il s'avère intelligent, ce produit s'avère excellent. [Dans les syntagmes ci-après] il y a en fait catachrèse, c'est-à-dire oubli du sens premier. (...). J'hésiterais à dire : cette nouvelle s'avère vraie, inexacte ou peu probable* ». L'usage courant les impose cependant de plus en plus, du moins dans une langue peu châtiée.

Voilà pourquoi tu l'as entendu dire, accompagné de la raison qui explique l'usage courant (l'oubli du sens premier).

Comment: Intéressant. Est-ce que ça veut dire que l'on devrait dire correctement *L'histoire du jeune homme est avérée* et l'inverse *(...) est démentie* ?

Comment: @LaurentG. Oui, ça se dit aussi, mais je ne pense pas qu'il faille être si effrayé des pléonasmes. On dit bien "aujourd'hui" voire "au jour d'aujourd'hui" - double pléonasme - sans choquer personne !

Answer (score 6):

C'est ce qu'on appelle un [pléonasme](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%A9onasme). Wikipedia en donne un bon nombre d'exemples:

- Je tourne en rond
- La marche à pied

Bien que ce soit généralement vu comme incorrect, les pléonasmes sont très utilisés dans la vie de tous les jours et certains constituent même des expressions très répandues (p. ex. : la marche à pied). Parfois, des auteurs vont même les utiliser comme figure de style (souvent en les exagérant).

Ils existent aussi en [anglais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm), mais semblent moins fréquents (à confirmer ...?)

Answer (score 1):

Je pense au contraire que c'est une phrase très correcte. "Avérée" prend ici un sens proche de "révelée", et "exacte" implique non seulement la vérité mais aussi l'entièreté.
Et comme souvent, l'usage du pléonasme sert aussi d'emphase afin de renforcer l'image.

On pourrait probablement remplacer l'expression par :

> L'histoire du jeune homme *s'est révelée juste en tout point*.

qui est plus consistant que :

> Il a dit vrai

Cette expression très pratique permet donc de préciser le sens tout en le renforçant.